# Creating custom nameserver for my VPS

Tags: vps

I know this is just a little question.
I still confuse about IP, domain, nameservers and DNS record work flow.

case:
I Buy a domain and VPS for my website. let say the domain was www.hengky.com,
the domain and vps has been configured by my provider and running well.
But, I check the ns for www.hengky.com are:
 - ns1.biz.net.id
 - ns2.biz.net.id

which is that's my provider ns. why they not just create and use ns1.hengky.com for my own ns?
So, I want create my custom ns like ns1.hengky.com **for my another website**,

My question is,
is it possible for me create my custom ns for my another domain, but still use ns1.biz.net.id for www.hengky.com??

(Because I don't want change my www.hengky.com's ns which is will make my website down for propagation time).

your guidance or tutorial link will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Nameservers Registration**

1) Login domain registrar panel of domain **hengky.com**.
2) Register following custom nameservers on domain **hengky.com** with IP address where your other websites's DNS zone reside.

ns1.hengky.com and 
ns2.hengky.com

**2) Add glue records at hengky.com's DNS zone**

Add following records at hengky.com's DNS zone.

ns1...........A...........IP address of server where your other websites's DNS zone reside.
ns2...........A...........IP address of server where your other websites's DNS zone reside.